# Get all the ids from a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list

I have this HTML:

```
<ul id="sortable" >
    <li class="myclass" id="1">One item</li>
    <li class="myclass" id="3">Another item</li>
</ul>
```

This list changes is not static. So the ids can change. How can I get all the ids (values) from this list?

Comment: You can use [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map) to build an array of the id values - however changing `id` attributes dynamically is a bad idea. They are designed to be static. If you want to change something to identify the elements, use classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map()` and return array of ids

```js
var ids = $('#sortable li').map(function() {
  return $(this).attr('id');
}).get();

console.log(ids)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="myclass" id="1">One item</li>
  <li class="myclass" id="3">Another item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$( ".myclass" ).each(function( ){
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   // this will return id
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all the `li` tags and get their id's into an array.

```js
 var arrayOfIds = [];

 $('#sortable li').each(function(){
   arrayOfIds.push($(this).attr('id'));
});

console.log(arrayOfIds);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="sortable" >
    <li class="myclass" id="1">One item</li>
    <li class="myclass" id="3">Another item</li>
   <li class="myclass" id="4">Yet Another item</li>
   <li class="myclass" id="5">And Another item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var IDs = [];
$("#sortable").find("li").each(function(){ IDs.push(this.id); });

console.log(IDs);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="sortable" >
    <li class="myclass" id="1">One item</li>
    <li class="myclass" id="3">Another item</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```